# Break a long string in a concatenation of shorter ones

Tags: string, wrapping

Is there a predefined way to split

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
```

in something like

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore " +
"et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut " +
"aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum " +
"dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui " +
"officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
```

I'm looking for a mode-aware word wrapping: I mean, the wrapping should take into account that the line is a string and the filled paragraph should made by a syntactically correct concatenation of strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform operations that are intended for buffers on strings with the help of temporary buffers.

1. Insert the string into a temporary buffer.
2. Switch on the desired major-mode.
3. Insert the string contents there,
4. Perform the operation on the temp buffer. (Here: `fill-region`)
5. Return the buffer string. (Maybe with some post-processing, as, e.g., splitting at newlines.

```el
(defun line-wrap-string (string &optional major-mode-fun trim)
  "Line-wrap STRING in temp-buffer according to MAJOR-MODE-FUN."
  (unless major-mode-fun
    (setq major-mode-fun #'text-mode))
  (split-string
   (with-temp-buffer
     (funcall major-mode-fun)
     (insert string)
     (fill-region (point-min) (point-max))
     (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)))
   "\n" t trim))
```

There are many variations of the theme. In some instances one does not need to fire up the full major mode but one only needs some properties of it (e.g., the syntax-table). Sometimes one avoids running the major mode hooks by binding the hook variable to nil...

Comment: Somebody downvoted. I am okay with that. But, if you downvote please leave a comment explaining the reason for the downvote. That would give me the chance to improve the answer.